# Skip to the next and previous photo by typing j/k or ←/→

Tags: wordpress, image, plugins, navigation, arrows

I'm trying to find a wordpress plugin or some kind of way to scroll through an article with images using left/right arrows. Like jumping to the next div :)

An example here: http://www.theatlantic.com/photo/2016/04/still-cleaning-up-30-years-after-the-chernobyl-disaster/476748/

I've seen this way of scrolling on multiple websites, but I can't manage to google it so I can have some results.
If anyone knows how can I do this, please be kind and share the knowledge :D

Thanks!

Comment: Try finding about onkeydown event and keycodes for the corresponding keys. In your case, keycode for j / k.

Comment: I managed to find this: http://jsfiddle.net/dY44L/82/

It's almost what I need, but I have to modify for key presses. Wish me luck, I'm a really noob coder :))

Comment: Best of luck. Proceed step by step and victory is yours. Enjoy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine helped me, this is the answer for whom it may concern:

```
// should smooth scroll be enabled?
var smooth_scroll = true;

// should we try to scroll to image's left side?
var horizontal_scroll = false;

// duration of smooth scroll (ms)
var duration = 100;

// pause (ms) between smooth scroll frame
var interval = 10;

// min area (px2) of image to include in navigation
var area = 10000;

// no more configurable settings below this comment

var img = document.getElementsByClassName('body-text')[0].getElementsByTagName('img');
var len = img.length;
var images = [];

for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    if (img[i].width * img[i].height >= area) {
        images.push(img[i]);
    }
}

len = images.length;

if (!len) {
    return;
}

document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    var key = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;

    switch (key) {
        case 74: // J
        case 75: // K

            var page_y = scrollY();
            index = -1;

            if (key == 75) {
                for (var i=len-1; i>-1; i--) {
                    position = getElementXY(images[i]);
                    if ((position.y + 5) <= page_y) {
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
                    position = getElementXY(images[i]);
                    if ((position.y - 5) >= page_y) {
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (index === -1) {
                return;
            }

            var position = getElementXY(images[index]);
            if (smooth_scroll) {
                var steps = duration / interval;
                var x_step = (horizontal_scroll ? Math.round((position.x - scrollX()) / steps) : 0);
                var y_step = Math.round((position.y - scrollY()) / steps);
                var step = 0;

                function smoothScrollBy() {
                    window.scrollBy(x_step, y_step);
                    if (++step < steps) {
                        setTimeout(smoothScrollBy, interval);
                    } else {
                        window.scrollTo(0, position.y);
                    }
                }

                smoothScrollBy();
            } else {
                scrollTo((horizontal_scroll ? position.x : 0), position.y);
            }

        break;
    }
};

function getElementXY(elem) {
    var x = 0,
            y = 0;

    while (elem.tagName != "BODY") {
        x += elem.offsetLeft;
        y += elem.offsetTop;
        elem = elem.offsetParent;
    }

    return { x: x, y: y };
}

function scrollX() {
    return window.pageXOffset ? window.pageXOffset : document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft;
}

function scrollY() {
    return window.pageYOffset ? window.pageYOffset : document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v18eLqos/4/

Hooray! :D

P.S. This is for j/k, for left case: 37, for right case:39